# Why Dio with Flutter does not post file with values using json header

Tags: flutter, dart, dio

I am new to Flutter

I am trying to pass data in json format and file on same request using dio framework. code I'm using is below, anything wrong I'm doing?

```
    return FormData.fromMap({
      'value1' : value.value1(),
      'value2' : value.value2(),
      "attachments": [
        await MultipartFile.fromFile(fileImage.path,
            filename: "storeName.jpeg")
      ]
    });
  }

static Future<bool> createStore(File fileImage, StoreDetails store) async{
    bool isDone = false;
    var dio = Dio();

    dio.options.baseUrl = UrlHelper.BASE_CORE_URL;
    dio.options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer '+ token;
    dio.options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';

    Response response;

    try{
      response = await dio.post(

        'Url',
        data: await formData(fileImage, values),
        onSendProgress: (received, total) {
          if (total != -1) {
            print((received / total * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%");
          }
        },
      );
      print(response.data);
      return true;
    }catch(e){
      print(e.toString());
      return true;
    }

  }
```

How I post data on postman
[image: values as json object]

[image: Screenshot for image file]

[image: Headers on postman]

And I get this error DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [415]
I am able to post image and json object from postman successfully.

Comment: you're trying to upload image file and send content type as  'application/json', how you think what's wrong?

Comment: Hey Eugene, I'm not following, you asking if I'm passing content as 'application/json' if that's the question, yes.

Comment: show headers from postman

Comment: https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/33501 There is an issue going on in flutter sdk , I think you can only send headers in lowercase.
Authorization to authorization
Content-Type to content-type

Comment: @Eugene I have added headers image from postman.

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP Error 415](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415) indicates that the payload that you're sending is unsupported. What you're trying to post using Postman is just text. The likely culprit here is that the endpoint that you're using doesn't support receiving image files that you're trying to send.